# RTP Proxy for Kamailio 4.1

Tags: kamailio

I'm following [this](http://saevolgo.blogspot.com/2013/08/rtpproxy-revisited-kamailio-40.html) post to setup RTP Proxy for `kamailio 4` but it's NOT working as predicted  and I'm receiving this error message on asterisk...

..............................................................................................

```
[2013-10-16 05:20:04] ERROR[3216][C-0000002c]: netsock2.c:269 ast_sockaddr_resolve: getaddrinfo("192.168.1.80192.168.1.80", "(null)", ...): Name or service not known
[2013-10-16 05:20:04] WARNING[3216][C-0000002c]: chan_sip.c:10873 process_sdp_c: Unable to lookup RTP Audio host in c= line, 'IN IP4 192.168.1.80192.168.1.80'
[2013-10-16 05:20:04] WARNING[3216][C-0000002c]: chan_sip.c:10464 process_sdp: Insufficient information in SDP (c=)...
```

...........................................................................................

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you call rtpproxy_manage() (or other alternative function from rtpproxy module) two times. The IP in SDP is invalid, being actually two times the IP.

Check your kamailio.cfg and be sure that the function engaging rtpproxy is executed only once.